# To use or not to use identity on a lookup table

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server I have the following lookup table that holds degree levels:

```
create table dbo.DegreeLevel 
( 
    Id int identity not null
       constraint PK_DegreeLevel_Id primary key clustered (Id),
    Name nvarchar (80) not null
       constraint UQ_DegreeLevel_Name unique (Name)
)
```

Should I use identity on the `ID`?

When should I use identity or a simple int in a lookup table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it comes down to whether or not you have a natural candidate to use in the clustered index...

If you already have a property that can uniquely identify the row, then its definitely worth considering whether adding an identity column is the right move.

If you don't have a natural candidate, then you'd need to invent a value and in this case using an identity column or sequence is probably easier than hand-rolling something.

As an example of having a natural key, imagine a 'DegreeModule' table where each module had a 4-character reference code that was printed on course materials (e.g. U212)

In this case, I would definitely skip creating an internal identifier and use the natural identifier as primary key...

```
create table dbo.DegreeModule 
( 
    Reference char(4) not null primary key clustered,
    Name nvarchar(80) not null
       constraint UQ_DegreeModule_Name unique (Name)

    /* .. plus FK's for stuff like parent degree, prerequisites,etc .. */
)
```

Answer (score 5):

After dealing with multiple environments where we move changes from one environment to the next, I'd say **not** to use identity columns on look up tables.

Here's why: if you need to reference an ID as a "magic #", you need consistency. Ideally, you wouldn't ever reference a magic #, but in reality, that is not what is commonly done. And it's a pain to correct when the IDs are out of sync. And it's really not much more effort to insert the table's data with an ID.

Comment: I know this Q&A is old but I thought I'd also add that in various ORM scenarios, lookup tables will map to `enum` values which are are declared in code.  I like to explicitly declare my enums and explicitly create the matching lookup records in a new table when starting a new project.  Over time, new lookup items might be added in development and the key values  _must remain the same_ when deployed to live. You can't ensure that's the case when the key column is an identity without enabling `identity_insert`. In all cases I can think of, stay away from identities for lookups!

Answer (score 3):

In a **lookup table**, having a "normal" `Id INT` might be better, because it gives you the ability to pick and choose the `Id` values. You get to define which values you have, and what they mean.

`Identity` is very useful for actual **data tables**, where you just need to know that you have a good, unique ID value - but you don't really care about what that value is.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify [Identity](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) property on an integer column on any table, the column becomes an auto-incrementing integer column. If you want your lookup table to create the id value automatically when you insert any row, use identity. if you want to create it yourself, just define the column as int.

- A Table can only have one identity column
- You cannot manually insert / update values in an identity column unless you specify `SET identity_insert on`

Comment: Yes, I know what identity does ... The question is if Identity should be used on a loockup table ... Any situation when this would be a bad idea?

Comment: In line with what marc_s mentioned, if you already have your reference lookup data and ids which are already defined and mean something, you don't need to use an identity column.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use some object relational mapping (**ORM**) tool, refer to its documentation. In that case, you most probably would like to allow **ORM** to handle the primary key and you should not use identity.

If you have **no specific requirements** for primary key generation, then using identity here **is fine**. Specific requirements may be: primary keys follow special format, primary keys should be globally unique, primary keys are imported from other database, e.g. by `insert into DegreeLevel values (1, 'Bachelor')` etc.